# How can I lock and unlock a screen during certain times of the day?

Tags: 10.04, screensaver

I'm using a low power PC as a updating status screen, using firefox at fullscreen mode and a plugin called "Reload Every".

M-F from 8 AM to 6 PM, I need the app set to no-screensaver and no-screenlock

Every other time I want the screen locked.

The purpose is basic security when no one else is around. I don't have to use gnome-screensaver to accomplish these goals. I just want to disable and enable the keyboard, mouse and screen without entering in a password, automatically.

I was thinking of using cron and a shell script or python to swap a config file, but the gnome-screensaver man page is a bit lacking, and I have no idea what it uses for configuration.

Comment: ah, never mind, but I'll keep the question up for google's sake.  ....

to lock from the command line:
....
gnome-screensaver-command -l
....
To unlock
....
gnome-screensaver-command -d
....
I should be able to stick this into crontab and test it shortly.

Comment: Could you answer your own question with "Post Your Answer" please. It will be useful for people searching for an answer in the future.

Comment: love to, except that askubuntu does not allow that at my experiance level for likew 72 hours, plus I need to test it in crontab anyway

Comment: @user886694 Quite some time has passed, so you should be able to post your own answer now. I highly recommend doing so!

Comment: If you have solved the issue could you post the answer, otherwise I might have a go at solving it

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to use a GUI, this can quite easily be done with [Cuttlefish](https://launchpad.net/cuttlefish), a "reaction based tool" that changes Ubuntu settings/appearance based on the environment (time of day, plugged in/out, connected to the internet, etc).

Two things need to be done. First, choose the environment when the action should take place. In this case the date & time.

[image]

Then choose which settings should change. In this case unlocking the screen and turning off the screensaver.

[image]

Cuttlefish is probably not the most resource-efficient option for this particular task but it's the easiest way I know of.

Answer (score 1):

user886694's solution above is not complete. You need to include 'export DISPLAY=:0.0' before your unlock and lock commands like this:

To lock the screen add this to crontab...

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

And to unlock...

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && gnome-screensaver-command -d
```

The best GUI tool I've found for adding crons through an interface is gnome-schedule which can be installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule
```

Once installed, the program will be called "Scheduled Tasks" in your 'Dash Home'. To use it, simply add a new task and enter a brief description, the command and time you want the lock or unlock to run.